# Font on emacs (Windows 10) appears cut off

Tags: microsoft-windows, fonts

How can I improve the appearance of the emacs (25.2.1) font on Windows 10 (1703)? Currently, text appears blurred and cut off (especially lines on the bottom):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to turn off the display scaling?

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option. My option says:
"Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: 1) Application, 2) System, 3) System (enhanced)". Thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: I can only suggest to try them all one by one